# Why was it Italy that attack ed Tripoli under Ottoman control in 1911?

Tags: world-war-one, ottoman-empire, the-balkans

This was the invasion that triggered off a lot of pre-WW1 events including the second Bulgarian war.

But why did Italy invade Tripoli in 1911? It would make sense to me if Austro-Hungary invaded it since it wanted to be the next superpower following the Ottoman Empire, but why Italy?

Comment: Welcome to History:SE. What has your research shown you so far? You might find it helpful to review the site [tour](https://history.stackexchange.com/tour) and [Help Centre](https://history.stackexchange.com/help) and, in particular, [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Italy, like Austria-Hungary, also wanted to be a Great Power. Unlike Austria-Hungary, Italy saw the road to this status in [the scramble for Africa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scramble_for_Africa). (Austria-Hungary preferred to try its luck in the Balkans.)

This was the country, remember, that first attacked [Abysinnia in 1895-6,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_Italo-Ethiopian_War) losing, then finally succeeding in 1934-5. The Ottoman Empire was known (in the 19th and early 20th centuries) as the ["Sick Man of Europe"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sick_man_of_Europe), except that it had holdings in North Africa. France had already taken away Morocco, Algeria, and Tunisia, leaving Libya for the Italians. This, they were able to do in [1912](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Italo-Turkish_War).

This happened because while Italy was "weak" compared to most other European countries including Austria-Hungary, it was "strong" compared to the Ottoman Empire.